# Laravel dompdf report using table html

Tags: dompdf, laravel-5.3

I tried to create a report PDF using HTML tables, but get an error like this.

> The row #36 could not be found, please file an issue in the tracker with the HTML code

Does anyone else know about this problem?

Comment: What's the HTML that you were using to convert it? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40512686/edit) your question and include that.

Comment: Also, did you file an issue with dompdf with details about this? https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues